# IE7 div oddity

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a menu which works perfectly in every browser except IE7 and I need a fresh pair of eyes because I can't seem to find the cause for this problem.

In the menu, there are items which have flags to the left seen here (edited to remove client's name):

[image: What the menu looks like in other browsers]

And this is what it looks like in IE7:

[image: What the menu looks like in IE7]

In IE7, I *think* the divs are fighting, thus the flag div sits on top of the div to the right and gets forced down, creating a break in the menu.

To better explain, here is the code for the menu (made of a styled unordered list):

```
<li id="menu_worldwide"><a href="javascript:;">WORLDWIDE</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/global.asp" id="launch_map">Worldwide Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="/map.asp" id="launch_map_plantyard">Plants &amp; Yards</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-ca.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
      <div class="menu_flag_link"> <a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/" target="_blank">Canada<br />
        <em class="language">(English)</em></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="menu_flag_2line"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-eu.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
      <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="javascript:;">Europe<br />
        <em class="language_nomargin">(Multi-language) </em><img src="/images/arrow.png" width="11" height="11" border="0" /></a></div>
      <ul class="left">
        <li>
          <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-gb.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
          <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/international/english/home.htm" target="_blank">UK<br />
            <em class="language">(English)</em></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-fr.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
          <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/international/francais/home.htm" target="_blank">France<br />
            <em class="language">(Fran&ccedil;ais)</em></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-de.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
          <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/international/deutsch/home.htm" target="_blank">Deutschland<br />
            <em class="language">(Deutsch)</em></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-es.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
          <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/international/espanol/home.htm" target="_blank">Espa&ntilde;a<br />
            <em class="language">(Espa&ntilde;ol)</em></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-nl.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
          <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/international/nederlands/home.htm" target="_blank">Nederland<br />
            <em class="language">(Nederlands)</em></a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="menu_flag"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-mx.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
      <div class="menu_flag_link"> <a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/" target="_blank">Mexicana<br />
        <em class="language">(espa&ntilde;ol)</em></a></div>
    </li>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    /*  left: auto;
    right: auto;
*/  top: 143px;
 #top: 135px; /* Fix for IE 7 only */
    width: 100%;
    height:28px;
    z-index:100000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #669900;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
}
/* remove all the bullets, borders and padding from the default list styling */
.menu ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
/* float the list to make it horizontal and a relative positon so that you can control the dropdown menu positon */
.menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    #padding: 0px;
    #margin: 0px;
}
/* style the links for the top level */
.menu a, .menu a:visited {
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    height:28px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #669900;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 26px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #333333;
    border-right-color: #333333;
    border-bottom-color: #333333;
    border-left-color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}
/* style the top level hover */
.menu a:hover, .menu ul ul a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.menu :hover > a, .menu ul ul :hover > a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.menu_flag_link {
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    #margin-left: 20px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
    #left: -20px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
    #top: 0px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
}
.language {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    #margin-left: 0px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
}
.language_nomargin {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.menu_flag_holder {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
}
.menu_flag {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    #margin-right: 35px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    #width: 16px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
    z-index: 100;
    #clear: both;
}
.menu_flag_2line {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    #margin-right: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    #margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    #width: 16px;/* Fix for IE 7 only */
    z-index: 100;
}
/* ---------------------------------------2-------------------------------------------------*/
/* style the second level background */
.menu ul ul a.drop, .menu ul ul a.drop:visited {
    background-color: #669900;
    background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 130px center;
}
/* style the second level hover */
.menu ul ul a.drop:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 130px center;
}
.menu ul ul :hover > a.drop {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 130px center;
}
/* style the second level links */
.menu ul ul a, .menu ul ul a:visited {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height:auto;
    line-height:normal;
    padding:5px 10px;
    width:160px;
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* yet another hack for IE5.5 */
* html .menu ul ul a, * html .menu ul ul a:visited {
    width:161px;
    w\idth:160px;
}
/* hide the sub levels and give them a positon absolute so that they take up no room */
.menu ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    top:28px;
    left:0;
    width:182px;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
}
/* another hack for IE5.5 */
* html .menu ul ul {
    top:30px;
    t\op:31px;
}
/* make the second level visible when hover on first level list OR link */
.menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul a:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
/* ---------------------------------------3-------------------------------------------------*/
/* style the third level background */
.menu ul ul ul a, .menu ul ul ul a:visited {
    background-color: #669900;
}
/* style the third level hover */
.menu ul ul ul a:hover {
    background:#000000;
}
/* position the third level flyout menu */
.menu ul ul ul {
    left:181px;
    top:-1px;
    width:182px;
}
/* position the third level flyout menu for a left flyout */
.menu ul ul ul.left {
    left:-181px;
}
/* style the table so that it takes no ppart in the layout - required for IE to work */
.menu table {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
/* keep the third level hidden when you hover on first level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
}
/* make the third level visible when you hover over second level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul :hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
/* ---------------------------------------4-------------------------------------------------*/


/* position the fourth level flyout menu */
.menu ul ul ul ul {
    left:181px;
    top:-1px;
    width:182px;
}
/* position the fourth level flyout menu for a left flyout */
.menu ul ul ul ul.left {
    left:-181px;
}
/* keep the fourth level hidden when you hover on second level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul :hover ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
}
/* make the fourth level visible when you hover over third level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

    <li>
      <div class="menu_flag_2line"><img src="/images/flags/Icons-flag-cl.gif" width="16" height="11" border="0"></div>
      <div class="menu_flag_link"><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/" target="_blank">Tuberias<br />
        <em class="language">(espa&ntilde;ol/portugu&ecirc;s)</em></a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The problem seems to be with the classes ".menu_flag_2line", ".menu_flag" and ".menu_flag_link"

I am completely stumped, anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: have you tried floating the menu_flag_link

Comment: I have tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using IE conditional comments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) to assign code specific to IE?

Comment: Try removing the IE7 only rules on the divs to get a clean slate. Next, float both divs left and make sure they have widths. What happens?

Comment: I had already tried that. The two divs just don't want to sit together.

Comment: I decided to use the Conditional comments since nothing else seemed to work. Thanks David Faux!

Answer (score 0):

need to wrap the 2 divs in a positioned element for IE7 to play nice:

```
ul.left li {position:relative; float:left; width:100%;}
```